# Ubuntu how to find and launch GUI app from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

The key is how to find the program name?

Say I have "Files" window. I know that it is actually "nautilus" from previous experience.

The big question is how can I make the connection from Files to nautilus. I cannot find nautilus anywhere in the program.

Similarly, how can I launch System Monitor, or any other programs that I can easily find in the apps or search bar, but not in the terminal.

I am using 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04 all LTS if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`.

These files contain path to the real application.

You can list these files by name with

```
grep 'Name=' /usr/share/applications/* > FileNames.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get to the folder and can see all the shortcuts, but I cannot find any .desktop files or any . files. If I check on the properties of the shortcuts I cannot find the path either. What am I missing?

Comment: That's the problem that now you can't open them by click. But you can `cat` them in a terminal.

Comment: Run `ls /usr/share/applications` and you'll see that all that are `.desktop` files.

Comment: I think I am catching on with ls -la I see nautilus.desktop and a whole bunch of files. However when I do cat nautilus.desktop I get a whole lot of information about it being a file manager, but nothing about the actual name "Files". Similarly I have no idea how to identify any of the other files? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question correctly. From 18.04 if , from terminal, I type 'nautilus' I get nautilus running. If, from nautilus I type 'nautilus' in search window I get 2 locations where there is nautilus.

Comment: You can see `Name=Files` there.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, it is right there at the very top. I could not see it at first. However, one last piece. I have over 200 entries in the applications folder. Is there any way to run cat on all of them and extract the name result and create mapping file on my Desktop? Thanks again.

Comment: BobRun, my issue is that I don't know it is called nautilus. I see "Files" in the GUI. The question is how to find out it is nautilus in a reasonable amount of time. Thanks.

Comment: You can run `grep 'Name=' /usr/share/applications/*`

Comment: So run `grep Name=Files /usr/share/applications/*`

Comment: Thanks got it. grep `'Name=' /usr/share/applications/* > /home/user/Desktop/FileNames.txt` This creates a file withe full path to the program followed by the Name field and I can deal with that. Please add the grep command to your answer. Thank again.

Comment: There should really be an easier more obvious way than this. There should be an info/about section which has this or (actually and) the "Show details" in the dash should give this information. This is blocking normal users from becoming power users, or just normal users from creating an optimal customization.